# Two consecutive candle total range, pine script

Tags: pine-script

I have a simple problem but i'm stupid too.
How can i get a range of two consecutive candles? I know i could just switch to higher time frame but i definitely need a certain time frame two (or more) consecutive candle combined range. Or, in other words, custom date range basically.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) for this.

`close[1]` refers to the previous close price and `close[2]` refers to the close price of two bars ago.

Comment: Yes, that i know. But i need the range of two bars and sometimes  i need the high of a previous bar and sometimes the low depending on market. But how?